# Error while run the server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got this error when i want to run my server on node localhost.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\iaSM\localMaBhaWebSrv.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: Apparently, `C:\iaSM\localMaBhaWebSrv.js` does not exist or is a wrong path.

Comment: C:\iaSM is my node path.
C:\iaSM>node localMaBhaWebSrv.js

Comment: See the relative path of `localMaBhaWebSrv.js` from the file its called.
Basically I use `RootOfTheProject\path\to\localMaBhaWebSrv.js` by using `resolve-path` module.

Comment: @souravlahoti can you just explain with a code sippet ?